# Freemarker Customize TemplateCache storage want to read the information from TemplateKey

Tags: java, templates, caching, customization, freemarker

I have my own customized freemarker template storage configured over freemarker, it is working fine.

Recently I want to make some changes on the cache management, I need to read the properties from the cache key which is typeof "TemplateKey". Unfortunately the "TemplateKey" is "private final static class". I have no access to this class and I cannot cast the Key object back into TemplateKey object.

I see the simplest way is to make source code change in TemplateCache.java to update the TemplateKey to be expose as public class.

Question to Freemarker designer: Is it any special reason to make this TemplateKey not be exposed? Is it possible to expose it in next build?

Thanks.

Rocky

Answer (score 0):

At the first glance, I would keep the key class private, because exposing it would introduce a backward-compatibility constraint that can be in the way of further development. But what exactly is your use case that require information from the key?

Answer (score 0):

We disabled localelookup, in this case, one FTL file are working for all locales. But the key includes locale, so sampe template was cached per locale, it is duplicated in memory.
One solution is: remove locale in key when manage it in cache, so I need read key properties. But it still need combine with other changes such as make template clone-able. 
Please refer to this POS for detail: [Freemarker Template Cache are in same content when locale are different, is it a concern on wasting memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22924831/freemarker-template-cache-are-in-same-content-when-locale-are-different-is-it-a)

Thanks.